# webjam js on vue js composition api

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api, webcam.js

My code get error when use this code:

```
<script setup>
import { requiredValidatorEng } from "@validators"
import api from "@/api/VisitorAPI"
import apiVR from "@/api/VisitReservationAPI"

import comboUtil from "@/utils/comboUtil"
import img from "@/img/picture.png"
import { DatetimeFormat } from "vue-i18n"
import Webcam from "webcamjs"
// import Webcam from "@/plugins/";
const swal = inject("$swal")
const formRef = ref()
const router = useRouter()

const loading = ref(false)
const urlImage1 = ref("")
const urlImage2 = ref("")
const urlImage3 = ref("")
const image1 = ref(null)
const image2 = ref(null)
const image3 = ref(null)

const combo = reactive({
visitorType: [],
departement: []
})

onMounted(async () => {
combo.visitorType = await comboUtil.doGetComboVisitorType()
Webcam.set({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    image_format: "jpeg",
    jpeg_quality: 90
})
Webcam.attach("#my_camera")
})

function take_snapshot() {
console.log("Webcam", Webcam)
Webcam.snap(function (data_uri) {
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "<h2>Here is your image:</h2>" + '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>'
})
}
</script>

<template>
<section>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>WebcamJS Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="results">Your captured image will appear here...</div>

        <h1>WebcamJS Test Page</h1>
        <h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>

        <div id="my_camera"></div>

        <form>
        <input type="button" value="Take Snapshot" @click="take_snapshot()" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
</section>
</template>
```

the error message in like belows:

> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:236 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'src')
> at func (webcam.js:840:13)
> at Object.snap (webcam.js:887:4)
> at Proxy.take_snapshot (add.vue:44:1)
> at _createElementVNode.onClick._cache.._cache. (add.vue:48:1)
> at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:173:22)
> at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:182:21)
> at HTMLInputElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:345:9)